# How to select a column with specific column value in SQL 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, distinct

I have table T1 containing two columns id and decision. id may be repeating for various decision. Please refer the example below:

```
 Table T1:
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      id             |     decision     |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      abc_0011       |      Forward     |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      abc_0011       |      Forward     |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      abc_0011       |      Reject      |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      abc_0012       |      Forward     |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      abc_0012       |      Forward     |
    |---------------------|------------------|

 Required Table:
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      id             |     decision     |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      abc_0011       |      Reject      |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      abc_0012       |      Pending     |
    |---------------------|------------------|
```

Here there are two distinct id **abc_011** and **abc_012**, abc_011 appears three time, with different decision where the last decision is Reject while abc_012 appears two times, where both the decision are forward and there is no decision like Reject. Idea is to construct a table where the id which at any stage is rejected must display reject and the id which is not rejected in any case must display pending. Note: the id must not repeat in the final table.

Comment: Only Forward and Reject are the decision field values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code should give you the expected results.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  ID,MAX(DECISION) DECISION
FROM T1
GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT  ID,CASE WHEN DECISION!='Reject' THEN 'Pending' ELSE DECISION END DECISION
FROM CTE
```